# How many ways to distribute humans into rooms?

Tags: combinatorics, combinations

How many ways can we distribute $10$ humans into $4$ rooms if:

- Rooms $1$ and $2$ need $3$ humans.
- Rooms $3$ and $4$ need $2$ humans.

I guess there are ${10\choose 3}$ ways for picking the humans in the first room. Then ${7\choose 3}$ ways for room $2$ and so on.

So I got ${10\choose 3}{7\choose 3}{4\choose 2}{2\choose 2} = 25200$

Is it ok?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, this is good, if we're keeping the rooms distinct from one another.

---

If Room $1$ and $2$ were indistinguishable from one another, and the same for Room $3$ and Room $4$, then we would have to divide our final answer by $(2)(2)=4$.

---

Say these rooms are distinguishable, but we need at least $1$ person in each.

We can do this easily using stars and bars. We first just place $1$ person in each, and we have $6$ people left in $4$ rooms. We have $3$ "bars", and so we can order the bars and stars[people] in $\displaystyle \binom{9}{3}$ ways.

---

If the rooms are indistinguishable as well, then we need the number of partitions of $10$ that have $4$ addends.

I'm not even going to try to find this, but you can look it up -- though I believe it is $9$ distinct partitions.

Comment: Thanks for your help. Maybe you can assist me with the next part, which asks: "Suppose want to assign each of $10$ humans to one of $4$ rooms. But now the $10$ humans are all identical clones of each other, so they are indistinguishable. How many ways can we put the $10$ humans in the $4$ rooms if each room needs at least $1$ person?" I think the answer is Stirling(10, 4) but perhaps I'm wrong. Not so sure because they are indistinguishable. Do you know this one?

Comment: i can try! let me edit my answer